# How to use st_Line_Locate_Point() with a MULTILINESTRING convertion in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis, plpgsql

I am trying to get the index position of a `POINT` in a `MULTILINESTRING`.

Here is the whole query I'm stuck with :

```
SELECT req.id, (dp).geom, netgeo_point_tech.id, ST_Line_Locate_Point(st_lineMerge(geom_cable), (dp).geom)
FROM (SELECT id, ST_DumpPoints(geom) as dp, geom as geom_cable FROM netgeo_cable_test ) as req
JOIN netgeo_point_tech ON ST_dwithin(netgeo_point_tech.geom, (dp).geom, 1) 
ORDER BY req.id, (dp).path [ 1] ASC
```

The error I get is : `line_locate_point : 1st arg isnt a line`.

The error is due to the return of `st_lineMerge()` function that is returning `LINESTRING` but also `MULTILINESTRING`.
I don't get this. `st_lineMerge()` is supposed to return only `LINESTRING`.[ST_LineMerge()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html)

When I jsut try a simple query like this :

```
select st_astext(st_linemerge(geom)) from netgeo_cable_test
```

The output is :

[image: img])

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: In your original query, you add a join to another table and you keep a subset only of the cable geometries. When merging this subset, the result is not a simple line anymore but a multi line, which makes st_lineLocatePoint fail.

Comment: @JGH I don't understand why it is not returning `LINESTRING` ? Because when I try the original query without the `ST_Line_Locate_Point()` function I get what I want.

Comment: @JGH Could you provide me an example or a beginning how to fix this ?

Comment: @JGH I found, I think, why my query is return false. `st_lineMerge()` is returning `MULTILINESTRING` too. See edit on the question.

Comment: you can break the multilines into multiple simple lines using `st_dump`

Comment: @JGH Damn dude it works perfectly !! Thank you so much!
However you should respond as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JGH for the suggestion to use ST_Dump I came up with this function:

```
create or replace function MultiLineLocatePoint(line geometry, point geometry) returns numeric as $$
select (base + extra) / ST_Length(line)
from (
    select 
        sum(ST_Length(l.geom)) over (order by l.path) - ST_Length(l.geom) base,
        ST_LineLocatePoint(l.geom, point) * ST_Length(l.geom) extra,
        ST_Distance(l.geom, point) dist
    from ST_Dump(line) l
) points
order by dist
limit 1;
$$ language SQL;
```

Comment: May need to change numeric to double precision.